How to determine the ITAR compatibility of a PyPI package?
I have used multiple PyPI packages in my project. I want to know whether each of them is ITAR compatible.
I have tried to find this information for tensorflow. I couldn't find the information in the GitHub README and license sections.
I am expecting a solid yes or no, which I could verify in the future. Also, is it safe to assume it isn't ITAR compliant if I do not find the info in either of these, viz., README and license?
If possible, I would be glad if there's an automated way to do this. As in, if a package name is given, I am expecting a boolean value indicating ITAR compatibility.

IANAL but would it not be reasonably safe to assume that if it's open source, it's not known to have issues? Fundamentally, this might be more suitable for [law.se].

Back when PGP was classified as a munition, the community went to great (some would say absurd) lengths to comply with the regulations. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#History

You don't specify which jurisdiction you're in. Under common law (i.e. roughtly speaking the Anglophone world), the answer to hard questions is often a solid "we don't know for sure until it has been tested in a court of law."

Barring that, the algorithm ls "pay a legal expert".

@tripleee I am from India


I am expecting a solid yes or no, which I could verify in the future.

That is not something you’re going to get. Few maintainers care even a little bit about ITAR compliance.

Also, is it safe to assume it isn't ITAR compliant if I do not find
the info in either of these, viz., README and license?

Sure, that would indeed be safe.

"Safe" but not necessarily optimal.

@tripleee That really depends on the individual's objectives. "Don't use anything whatsoever that isn't appropriately certified" is not an uncommon approach to software (and other engineering) in certain fields.
